# Select list is not binding to view model value after posting

Tags: select, asp.net-core

When posting from a form in an ASP.NET Core MVC project a select input item is not binding to the value in the model.

I've followed several guides that are all saying the same thing for how to do this including the official MSDN guide to select input tag helper, but the selected value is still not binding to my view model variable.

cshtml:

```
<form asp-action="Search" method="post">
    <select asp-for="SourceTypeId" asp-items="Model.SpellSources"></select>
</form>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SpellsVM
{
    public string Title = "Spells";
    public List<CheckBoxModel> Eras { get; set; }
    public List<CheckBoxModel> Classes { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SpellSources { get; set; }
    public List<SpellSearchResult> SpellSearchResults { get; set; }                
    public int SourceTypeId;

    public SpellsVM()
    {
        SpellSources = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Eras = new List<CheckBoxModel>();
        Classes = new List<CheckBoxModel>();
    }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Search(SpellsVM vm)
{
    vm.SourceTypeId // Always ZERO
    return View(vm);
}
```

`vm.SourceTypeId` is always zero on posting. I do see the value coming through in the `Request.Form`, for example:

```
Request.Form["SourceTypeId"] = 2
```

But why isn't it showing in the `ViewModel` value of `SourceTypeId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after breaking this down a piece at a time I found out the issue was my SourceTypeID property did not have get/set modifiers. The following change fixed the problem.

```
public int SourceTypeId { get; set; }
```